# Outlook rule move all mails to another e-mail account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

Is there a way to move all e-mails to another e-mail account (both accounts are added in Outlook 2016) older than a specifik date?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Archive emails in the second account to an archive.pst file. Archive everything older than 1 year. Now import this archive.pst file into the first account.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can create outlook rules to move messages before a specified date to another folder. For specific steps, please refer to:

1.File>Info>Manage Rules & Alerts>New rule…>***Apply rule on messages I receive***;

2.Under Select condition(s), choose ***received in a specific date span***>click ***in a specific date spa***n below, select ***Before*** and choose the specific date you want>Ok>Next;
[image]

3..Under Step1:Select action(s), choose ***move it to the specified folder***>Click ***specified*** below>choose the folder you want to move>Ok>Next;
[image]

4.Next>Finish.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.